# org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Soy nuevo en Spring Boot, y estoy haciendo un proyecto donde aplico los métodos del CRUD, estoy mirando tutoriales de los métodos y investigando el funcionamiento de esta, pero me encontrado con un contratiempo, ya que en el formulario que tengo en "usuarios.html" cuando le doy al botón de "editar" quiero que el formulario se refleje todos los valores del objeto (usuariosUpdate) en los input, pero este al cargar el proyecto me da una excepción y no me funciona el botón.
He buscado maneras de poder reflejar esos valores pero por mi falta de conocimiento sobre la herramienta no sé por donde buscar más a fondo con ejemplos, intente aplicar lo del objeto en el formulario para luego en los input poner los valores del mismo objeto, pero al hacerlo me da la excepción del titulo.
Yo pasó todo el código del controlador por si ahí un error en mi lógica.
En el código de html hay una data table pero dudo que afecte en algo.
Anexo el Código:
Este es el controlador

```
@Controller
public class usuarioController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("usuarioService")
    private CustomUserService CUS;

    @GetMapping("/usuarios")
    public ModelAndView tablaUsuarios(){
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("usuarios");
        mav.addObject("user", CUS.listOfUsuarios());
        // mav.addObject("user1", new usuarios());
        return mav;
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/addUser")
    public String addUsers(@ModelAttribute usuarios userRegister, HttpSession session){
        System.out.println(userRegister);
        if(CUS.addUser(userRegister) != null){
            session.setAttribute("message", "Usuario se agregó correctamente.");
            return "redirect:/usuarios";
        }
        session.setAttribute("alert", "El Usuario ya existe.");
        return "redirect:/usuarios";
    }
// Este es el método para obtener los datos del usuario, y reflejarlos en el formulario
    @GetMapping("/listData/{user_cedula}")
    public String dataUser(@PathVariable long user_cedula,Model model){
        Optional<usuarios> usuarios = CUS.listOfUserCedula(user_cedula);
        model.addAttribute("usuariosUpdate", usuarios);
        return "usuarios";
    }


    @PostMapping("/updateUser")
    public String updateUser(HttpSession session, @ModelAttribute usuarios userRegister){
        if(CUS.updateUser(userRegister) != null){
            session.setAttribute("message", "Se actualizo correctamente el usuario");
            return "redirect:/usuarios";
        }
        session.setAttribute("alert", "El Usuario no existe.");
        return "redirect:/usuarios";
    }
}
```

Este es el codigo del método de listOfUserCedula()

```
// Este es la interfaz
@Autowired
    @Qualifier("usuariosRepository")
    public usuariosRepository ur;

@Override
    public Optional<usuarios> listOfUserCedula(long user_cedula) {
        return ur.findById(user_cedula);        
    }
```

Este es el código HTML con el nombre de usuarios.html solo en la parte que necesito, anexo los estilos por si al caso

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- MDB CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Usuarios</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--table-->
    <div id="intro">
        <div class="p-70 h-100">
            <div class="container">
                <!--table-->
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="datatable" class="table table-borderless table-striped align-middle">
                        <thead class="table-dark text-center">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Cédula</th>
                                <th scope="col">Nombre de Usuario</th>
                                <th scope="col">Usuario</th>
                                <th scope="col">Rol</th>
                                <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody class="text-center">
                            <tr th:each="usuarios : ${user}">
                                <td scope="row" th:text="${usuarios.user_cedula}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${usuarios.user_name}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${usuarios.username}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${usuarios.roles}"></td>
                                <td th:text="${usuarios.user_email}"></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="crud">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"
                                            th:href="@{/listData/}+${usuarios.user_cedula}" data-mdb-toggle="modal"
                                            data-mdb-target="#editarModal">
                                            Editar
                                        </button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                            Eliminar
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!-- End table-->
                <!--Modal Editar-->
                <div class="modal fade" id="editarModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editarModalLabel"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="editarModalLabel">Editar Usuario</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-mdb-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Cencelar">
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <form class="p-3" th:action="@{/updateUser}" th:object="${usuariosUpdate}" method="POST">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_cedula_update"
                                                th:field="*{user_cedula}">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="user_cedula_update">Cédula</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{user_name}"
                                                name="user_name_update">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="user_name">Nombre Completo</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{user_email}"
                                                name="user_email">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="user_email">Email</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row mb-0 mb-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-outline col-12 mb-4 mb-md-0 col-md">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{username}"
                                                name="username">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="username">Usuario</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class=" col-12 mb-4 mb-md-0 col-md-3">
                                            <select class="form-select" aria-label="Select roles" name="roles"
                                                th:field="*{roles}">
                                                <option th:value="ADMIN" th:text="Admin"></option>
                                                <option th:value="USER" th:text="Usuario"></option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="form-outline col-12">
                                            <input type="password" class="form-control" th:field="*{password}"
                                                name="password">
                                            <label class="form-label" for="password">Contraseña</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button class="btn btn-color" type="submit">Modificar</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-mdb-dismiss="modal">
                                        Cancelar
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MDB Script -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/3.6.0/mdb.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Agrego el modelo

```
@Entity
public class usuarios {

    @Id
    private Long user_cedula;

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String user_email;
    private String user_name;
    private String roles;

    //Getters y Setters 
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tras mirar el código veo que el valor que estas pasando al template en el `usuariosUpdate` del método `dataUser(@PathVariable long user_cedula,Model model)` es un Optional y no el objeto de tipo `usuarios`, debes recoger el objeto del Optional a traves del método `get()` del mismo quedando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
    @GetMapping("/listData/{user_cedula}")
    public String dataUser(@PathVariable long user_cedula,Model model){
        Optional<usuarios> usuarios = CUS.listOfUserCedula(user_cedula);
        model.addAttribute("usuariosUpdate", usuarios.get());
        return "usuarios";
    }
```

Para que el método fuera mas correcto deberías hacer también ciertas comprobaciones sobre el valor del Optional ya que es un objeto que puede o no tener valor(este último caso dándose por ejemplo en el caso de que no exista el usuario en la base de datos). Para ello te recomiendo los métodos `isPresent()` o `isEmpty()` del propio Optional. Por ejemplo:

```
        @GetMapping("/listData/{user_cedula}")
        public String dataUser(@PathVariable long user_cedula,Model model){
            Optional<usuarios> usuarios = CUS.listOfUserCedula(user_cedula);
            if(!usuarios.isPresent()) {
                //redireccion a una ventana de error o alguna otra acción
            } else {
                model.addAttribute("usuariosUpdate", usuarios.get());
            }
            return "usuarios";
        }
```

Por otro lado he visto que a los inputs tienen el atributo `name`, este atributo es innecesario ya que el `th:field` al traducirlo se pone como `name`

Comment: he hecho los cambios que indicaste pero aun me sale error y lo que me indica la consola es que el error se produce cuando ejecuto esta fracción de código en el input (th:field="*{user_cedula}"), Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'usuariosUpdate' available as request attribute

Comment: @JuanRuiz puede que sea al intentar renderizar la vista sin añadir el atributo usuariosUpdate, he visto que siempre cargas la vista usuarios pero no siempre añades  el  `model.addAttribute("usuariosUpdate", usuarios);` prueba a añadirselo aunque sea un objeto vacio